# How can I find some threshold values for each/few features, that decides if the record belongs to class True or False. XGboost Classifier

Tags: dataframe, classification, decision-tree, xgboost

I have 10 features and my target is Boolean, I am running xgb tree classifier and I can plot trees and features importance. What I am trying to get is a value(threshold) for each of those 10 or less features that is crucial to determine if (X > X_value : belongs to class True else false).

Like here we see a value for age which determines the classification, I want this for each feature in a dataframe:

[image: like here we see a value for age which determines the classification, I want this for each feature in a dataframe]